# How to integrate CKFinder to CKEditor in ASP.NET - MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ckeditor, ckfinder

I integrate CKEditor in my MVC 3 application. But I couldn't integrate CkFinder to CKEditor. I read documents

I wrote this code in my view.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/ckeditor/ckeditor.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/ckfinder/ckfinder.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
  var editor = CKEDITOR.replaceClass("ckeditor");
  CKFinder.setupCKEditor(editor, '/ckfinder/');
</script>
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[CKEDITOR.replaceClass](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.html#.replaceClass) is a property, not a method so you should have an error right there.
All you need is the second call with a null editor and using the proper folder, maybe something like

```
CKFinder.setupCKEditor(null, '@Url.Content("~/ckfinder/")');
```